# CMake trying to find deleted source file

Tags: cmake

Im trying to run a cmake file, however i keep getting an error in which cmake is trying to find a source file, however I have already deleted this source file since i do not need it, but no matter which directory i make the new cmake file, it keeps throwing an error trying to find this deleted file even though its not used at all.

I have deleted the old project, and removed the old cmake files however i still get this error.

Comment: Does or did your project use `file(GLOB)`?

Comment: no, i am following a guide, and the first time i did it, it ran and worked and today I tried to add a new header file, and thats when the error started. Ive tried to remove it but i still get the error

Comment: You need to add the code and the exact error message into the question post. Otherwise we simply cannot help you. As a new person on Stack Overflow, you may find useful [ask].